# Different collision effects on different objects

Tags: collision-detection

I'm a beginner to Corona and game development. I am using a variety of objects in my game. On collision, they all perform the same function. I want them to do different things, and also want some objects to only collide with certain other objects. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collision events parameters for the objects involved in a collision. The parameters are named "other" or "other1" depending how how exactly you setup the collision event listener. Here's the documentation:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection#Global_collision_listeners

To have control which objects actually collide use collision masking:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection#Collision_categories_masking_and_groups